# Refresh WPF usercontrol when navigated to it

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, user-controls, microsoft-metro

I'm new to WPF and now i'm making an app that gets some data from MS SQL Server, places it to the table and allows to modify it. I'm using a M:UI template to make my app look metro-styled. My app structure: MainWindow.xaml and some UserControls placed into it with Itemsource="page" etc. Navigation between UserControls is made with Links and LinkGroups, generated upon MainWindow after successful login.

What I want is to launch a method that gets data from SQL every time I go to any of UserControls. Data is retrieved from server with **SQLDataReader** and placed to the **ObservableCollection** (one UserControl - one collection). At this moment my method works fine when I first go to any of UserControls, because it's placed to the constructor of the UserControl class, and I want to get some changes in all my tables when some other table was edited. How can I do this? Is there an event I can raise or some other way to update a table?

Answer (score 0):

Since communicating constantly or background tasks running  for server might take overhead and bit of memory wastage so I prefer u start using push notification :) Here's the link that will guide you through the push notification

[Push Notification Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx)

[Raw Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj676791.aspx)

Please go through them design the proper object to pass to you app and to display in the table :) Once you receive a change notification you can map that object to the table you are using .... or **read through the sql reader all the records** but that wont be a good practice to send all the records so you can go ahead fetch the latest data and append it to the table ... next time when user visits the page it will obviously be refreshed :)